# Union of finite union of finite intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \bigcap_{j=1}^m A_{ij}$ and $B = \bigcup_{k=1}^p \bigcap_{l=1}^q B_{kl}$  two sets. I want to find $C_{rs}$ such that
\begin{align}
A \cup B = \bigcup_{r=1}^{n+p} \bigcap_{s=1}^{m+q} C_{rs}
\end{align}

I tried to rewrite the union in this way
\begin{align}
A \cup B = \bigcup_{k=1}^p \bigcap_{l=1}^q \bigcup_{i=1}^n \bigcap_{j=1}^m (A_{ij} \cup B_{kl})
\end{align}
but now I don't see how to get the result.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted a less trivial approach than this, but this satisfies your conditions: Take

$$
C_{rs}=
\begin{cases}
A_{rs}&1\le r\le n\land1\le s\le m\;,\\
B_{r-n,s}&n\lt r\le n+p\land1\le s\le q\;,\\
A\cup B&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}
$$

Then

$$
\bigcap_{s=1}^{m+q}C_{rs}=
\begin{cases}
\bigcap_{j=1}^mA_{rj}&1\le r\le n\;,\\
\bigcap_{l=1}^qB_{{r-n},l}&n\lt r\le n+p\;,
\end{cases}
$$

so

$$
\bigcup_{r=1}^{n+p}\bigcap_{s=1}^{m+q}C_{rs}=\left(\bigcup_{r=1}^n\bigcap_{j=1}^mA_{ij}\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{r=n+1}^{n+p}\bigcap_{l=1}^qB_{{r-n},l}\right)=A\cup B\;.
$$

The last case $C_{rs}=A\cup B$ is just an arbitrary choice to keep the additional sets from reducing the intersection; if you don’t like the fact that $A\cup B$ appears there, you can use suitable $A_{rj}$ and $B_{rl}$ instead. (Or you could do away with these seemingly unnecessary sets altogether.)

Comment: *(Or you could do away with these seemingly unnecessary sets altogether.)* I'm not sure about this; after all, any element in $A \cup B$ (after rewritten using sets $C_{ij}$) must be in the intersection of all such $C$. Picking suitable $A_{ij}$ or $B_{ij}$ certainly works, though.

Comment: @MacRance: But these elements are already in one of the other sets; we don't need further intersections with $A\cup B$ to get them.

Comment: I was thinking that for any fixed $r$ and an $x \in A$ witnessed by $r$ we must have that $x \in C_{rs}$ for *every* $s \leq m+q$. Maybe I just misunderstand what you meant by *do away*

Comment: @MacRance: We certainly do. I meant more generally, since these sets aren't contributing anything and we're just adding them because the problem requires there to be $m+q$ of them, we could change the problem and just have $m$ of them for $1\le r\le n$ and $q$ of them for $n\lt r\le n+p$.

Comment: Ok yes, I'm totally with you. It really just is a technical requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An element $x$ is in $A$ if there is an $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that for for every $1 \leq j \leq m$ we have $x \in A_{ij}$, and similarly for $B$. Now assume you're given $x$. So you need to check whether $$ \exists 1 \leq i \leq n \; \forall 1 \leq j \leq m \; (x \in A_{ij}) $$ Suppose you've checked all such pairs $(i,j)$. Now, *after* checking these pairs, you need to check all pairs $(p,q)$ that range over the sets $B_{pq}$. Can you combine these two searches into one by fiddling with indices? What can you do with boundary cases?

SOLUTION:

> As suggested, do the search in stages: so define $$ C_{rs} = \begin{cases} A_{rs} & \text{if } 1 \leq r \leq n \text{ and } 1 \leq s \leq m\\ B_{r-n,s-m} & \text{if } n+1 \leq r \leq n+p \text{ and } m+1 \leq s \leq m+q\\ A_{11} & \text{if } 1 \leq r \leq n+p \text{ and } m+1 \leq s \leq q\\ B_{11} & \text{if } n+1 \leq r \leq p \text{ and } 1 \leq s \leq m+q \end{cases} $$ The $r$ value tells us whether we are searching over the $A$s or the $B$s, the $s$ coordinate ranges over the respective sets. What if $r$ tells us we search over the $A$s, but we have already checked all sets of the form $A_{ri}$ (ie the boundary case)? We can fill the remaining sets $C_{ri}$ with $i > m$ with any $A_{ij}$ we like. This holds because if $x \in A$ for this specific $r$ then $A$ is in the intersection of the $A_{ri}$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$, so adding another copy doesn't make a difference. If $x$ isn't in there, we don't need to worry anyway.